# Brownian Motion Question - Requires Verification

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose $Z(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion process with $Z(0)=0$, then calculate: $P(Z(3)>Z(2)>0)$

I have the following, but unsure if my rationale is correct:

$Z(3)=X_1+X_2+X_3, Z(2)=X_1+X_2$
Then $P(Z(3)>Z(2)>0)=P(X_1+X_2+X_3>X_1+X_2>0)=P(X_3>0)\cdot P(X_1+X_2>0)$

Finally we have $P(X_3>)\cdot P(Z(2)>0)=\frac{1}{4}$

Is this correct?

Comment: You are somewhat close, but I believe you need the independent increments. Can you write the sets $\{Z(3)>Z(2)\}$ and $\{Z(2)>0\}$ as a intersection of increments? Btw, I don't think X is defined.

Answer (score 2):

As Henrik suggested you have to use independent increments and the fact, that they are normal distributed. We have $\{Z(3)>Z(2)\}=\{Z(3)-Z(2)>0\}$, where $Z(3)-Z(2)\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Moreover, $\{Z(2)>0\}=\{Z(2)-Z(0)>0\}$, since $Z(0)=0$. Again, $Z(2)-Z(0)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,2)$.

We have $\{Z(3)-Z(2)>0\}\cap\{Z(2)>0\}=\{Z(3)>Z(2)>0\}$. Using independence of the increments of Brownian Motion, we get

$$P(Z(3)>Z(2)>0)= P(\{Z(3)-Z(2)>0\}\cap\{Z(2)>0\})=P(Z(3)-Z(2)>0)P(Z(2)>0)$$

Using the distribution above, I leave it to you to calculate this numerically.